# Codeigniter form validation - match one field to one of multiple fields

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

Is there a possibility to match one field to one of multiple fields with form validation?

Like field 'answer' matches 'optiona' OR 'optionb' OR 'optionc' OR 'optiond'.

I have this so far.

Rules for the correct answer:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('answer', 'antwoord', 'required|max_length[100]');
```

Rules for option A, B, C and D.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('optiona', 'Optie A', 'required|max_length[100]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('optionb', 'Optie B', 'required|max_length[100]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('optionc', 'Optie C', 'required|max_length[100]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('optiond', 'Optie D', 'required|max_length[100]');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally confused as to what you're trying to accomplish here. I think you'd have to use a callback. Something like:

```
public function check_answers($answer) {
    if (($answer == $this->input->post('optiona') || ($answer == $this->input->post('optionb')) {
        return TRUE;
    }
}

$this->form_validation->set_rules('answer', 'antwoord', 'required|max_length|callback_check_answers);
```

Hopefully that makes sense, I guess.